# describe boost multi_index iterator type by its index tag

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Using boost multi-index, I happen to have the following type for the iterator:

```
multi_index_set::nth_index<2>::type::iterator
```

I'd like go get rid of the `nth_index<2>` part of the type and refer to it via its index tag:

```
multi_index_set::tag_index<price_index>::type::iterator //tag_index is the functionality i'd like to have
```

Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `price_index` is the tag, you can refer to the relevant index iterator like this:

```
multi_index_set::index<price_index>::type::iterator
```